# Проблемы с многоуровневым меню в Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Помогите пожалуйста, у меня есть несколько вопросов. Как убрать то, что пункты в левом меню дублируются? После замены ссылки в пункте "О компании" с /company/ на /company/index.php или /company при нажатии на пункт выдаётся ошибка 404 nginx.[image: дублирующиеся пункты]
Второй вопрос, как убрать постоянное подсвечивание пункта "О компании" при переходах на другие страницы/разделы?

[image: лишнее подсвечивание]

И 3, как сделать так чтоб при переходе на другие разделы, меню оставалось общим, а не уменьшалось до пунктов выбранного раздела?

[image: в каком виде нужно меню с открытым подразделом, только плюс подсвечивание]
[image: то как это выглядит в данный момент при нажатии на пункт]

Код компонента левое меню:

```
<?if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>
 
<?if (!empty($arResult)):?>
<div class="sb_nav">
<ul>
 
<?
$previousLevel = 0;
foreach($arResult as $arItem):?>
 
    <?if ($previousLevel && $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] < $previousLevel):?>
        <?=str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel - $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"]));?>
    <?endif?>
 
    <?if ($arItem["IS_PARENT"]):?>
    
        <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>
                
            <li class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>current <?endif?>close"><span class="sb_showchild"></span>
                <a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>">         
                    <span><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></span>
                </a>
                <ul>
        
        <?else:?>
            <li class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>current <?endif?>open"><span class="sb_showchild"></span>
                <a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>">
                    <span><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></span>
                </a>
                <ul>
        <?endif?>
                                
 
    <?else:?>
 
        <?if ($arItem["PERMISSION"] > "D"):?>

            <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>
                <li class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>current <?endif?>close">
                    <a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>">
                        <span><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?else:?>
                <li class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>current <?endif?>open">
                    <a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
                </li>
            <?endif?>

        <?endif?>
 
    <?endif?>
 
    <?$previousLevel = $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"];?>
 
<?endforeach?>
 
</ul>
 
</div>
<?endif?>
```

Comment: Код компонента здесь не важен. Проблема в источнике данных для меню. Похоже, источником является инфоблок. Вот и проверьте его структуру: разделы и подразделы.

Comment: @Виктор Карев почему источник инфоблок? В меню же просто ссылки на файлы или папки. Кстати, попробовал переименовать index.php в company.php и указать ссылку на этот файл, как на корневой в разделе, вроде помогает. Но тогда сверху у главного меню пропадает выпадающее, а там оно нужно.

Comment: Потому что /company/index.php выдаёт, как ты говоришь, 404 ошибку. Значит, ссылка /company/ не на настоящий каталог,  а на псевдокаталог. Смотри в настройках правила обработки адресов.

Comment: Там для /company/ нет правил, попробовал создать, ничего не поменялось. Могу ещё добавить что при /company/index.php адрес в браузере почему то выводится ссылка без порта -http://localhost/company/. При /company/ ссылка имеет вид http://localhost:8001/company/

Comment: Если источник не инфоблок, и каталог /company/ физически существует, то смотри структуру файлов .left.menu.php в этом каталоге и подкаталогах.

Comment: Первым пунктом идёт <?
$aMenuLinks = Array(
 Array(
  "О компании", 
  "/company/index.php", 
  Array(), 
  Array(), 
  "" 
 ), А не может ли быть дело в конфигурации сервера nginx?

Comment: Указанный пункт говорит, что первый пункт меню имеет название "О компании" и при клике по нему идёт переход на "/company/index.php". Если этот файл  .left.menu.php лежит в /company/, то первый пункт явно лишний, поскольку указывает на тот же адрес. Надо его убрать - и всё.

Comment: По сути да, это бы решило проблему, но по шаблону там должен быть этот пункт в качестве стартовой страницы и подсвечиваться при клике по верхнему меню. Похоже дело было в настройке сервера (я использовал docker сборку). Поставил виртуальную машину битрикс с оф. сайта и всё заработало как надо (при переходе по /company/index.php ошибки не возникает).